# How Does this TypeScript Constructor Work? A Default Object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

How does the last argument of this constructor work?

```
    constructor(clientId: string, authority: string, tokenReceivedCallback: tokenReceivedCallback,
        {
            validateAuthority = true,
            cacheLocation = 'sessionStorage',
            redirectUri = window.location.href.split("?")[0].split("#")[0],
            postLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl = true
        }:
            {
                validateAuthority?: boolean,
                cacheLocation?: string,
                redirectUri?: string,
                postLogoutRedirectUri?: string,
                navigateToLoginRequestUrl?: boolean,
            } = {}) {

        ...

    }
```

It would seem to me, it takes in an object and the object has been defaulted if nothing is provided, correct?

If I want to override **one** of the values, say, cacheLocation, how do I do that?  Can I pass `{ cacheLocation: 'localStorage' }` or do I have to define all properties in that case?

---

Source: [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answers:

> It would seem to me, it takes in an object and the object has been defaulted if nothing is provided, correct?

Correct.

> If I want to override **one** of the values, say, cacheLocation, how do I do that?  Can I pass `{ cacheLocation: 'localStorage' }` or do I have to define all properties in that case?

Yes, you can provide just `cacheLocation` and the rest will get the defaults.

---

#### Explanation

When it comes to default values, you need to go from out to in.

First, you have `= {}`. That means that you can call the constructor without an object:

```
new Whatever("hello", "world");
```

---

Next, you have object property bindings with default values such as `cacheLocation = 'sessionStorage'`. This means that TypeScript will try to grab a property from the object named `cacheLocation`. If `cacheLocation` is `undefined`, then it'll use the default (`'sessionStorage'`), but otherwise TypeScript will use whatever was passed in.

That means if you only pass in an object with `validateAuthority` but not `redirectUri`, `redirectUri` will get its default value, but validateAuthority will use whatever you passed in.

---

All of this comes together for an easier-to-use API. The outermost default (`= {}`) will get used when no options are given. In an empty object (`{}`), properties like `cacheLocation` and `validateAuthority` will be `undefined`. 
And when those properties are `undefined` in the original object, the innermost defaults will get used in their place.

---

When in doubt, [try it out in the TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/). Just paste in the following:

```
class C {
    constructor(
        {
            validateAuthority = true,
            cacheLocation = 'sessionStorage',
            redirectUri = window.location.href.split("?")[0].split("#")[0],
            postLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
            navigateToLoginRequestUrl = true
        }:
            {
                validateAuthority?: boolean,
                cacheLocation?: string,
                redirectUri?: string,
                postLogoutRedirectUri?: string,
                navigateToLoginRequestUrl?: boolean,
            } = {}) {
    }
}

new C();

new C({ cacheLocation: 'asdbsgs' });
```

Comment: thanks Daniel!  I tried the playground and I can't get it work.  I pasted the above in the left, I clicked run on the right and I get a blank new page.  What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Hitting "Run" just runs your code, so you might need a `console.log` statement to see something appear in your browser's console.